# Circuit to move a 12v actuator both ways?

Tags: power, electronics

I'm trying to build a system that at a specific hour, will slowly lift one side of the mattress (to almost literally "kick you out of bed"), then a while later put it back down. I was planning on using a linear actuator like  [this one](https://www.amazon.es/ECO-WORTHY-Actuator-Tracker-Multi-function-Electroic/dp/B0171NTP86/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1491151403&sr=8-2&keywords=linear%2Bactuator&th=1). The motor speed is not really important, but should be able to go both ways.

I have no problem with the coding, but I know nothing of building electric circuits except the very basics (i don't even know where i'm supposed to connect the "ground"), and as the actuator uses 12V but the PI only gives up to 5, and probably needs bigger amperage too, I don't know how to hook everything, what power source or sources I should use, etc.

¿Could anyone give me some pointers as to what do I need to use and how to hook it? I have no problem with having to learn much, but I'd rather not buy anything that is not gonna work.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavored corner of StackExchange. As is, your question is far too broad for this format. This site isn't meant to be a tutorial, or discussion board. If you need something of that nature, I'd suggest the [official RPi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/). This site works best with questions that are specific in nature and have easily identifiable components.

Comment: Agreed that this is not meant to be an instructible, but just the same I went ahead and provided just enough of an answer to offer a jump-start.  I've been meaning to do my own Q&A on the topic of combining Rpi with Nano in the fashion described below.  So at least this is now in the database.

Answer (score 1):

What a cool idea.  I use those linear actuators for my solar panels, which have to adjust in both ways.  Here is how I do it:

Use 4 relays - one pair to switch power on, then the second set to select polarity.

This is what I have done for my solar tracking system.  It takes 4 pins to make it work (active-low).  You can get 4 relays on a single board, like this:

[image: 4x 5V relays on one board]

The way I set things up I always use Rpi and Arduino Nanos together, connected by a serial cable.  I have the Arduino IDE on the Pi so I can change the Nano  program any time.  Access to the Rpi is via RDP/WiFi.

The Arduino does the actual relay control, since it requires 5V triggers.

The Rpi gets the time from the Internet and communicates to the Arduino via the serial cable.  Like this:

[image: Pi connected to Nano]

This one is on the workbench being configured to read battery voltage and sky intensity then send the results on to the Pi.  My solar tracker and actuators have their own small (50W) solar panel and a marine battery, so this will add more data to the mix.  *The same battery is used by the other circuit with the relays, to power the actuators (I have 3 in my system, moving 2 panels each).  It has a small pair of solar cells to sense the position of the sun and act accordingly.*

A typical string coming in from this would look like

```
1\t13.83\t3645\n
```

where 1 is a sequence number (arbitrary - increments with each reading), 13.83 is the voltage reading, and 3645 is the light sensor output in Lux.  Note that the Arduino sends as few characters as possible.

Here is the Pi program that receives the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
from datetime import datetime
tab = "\t"
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
while True :
    linein = ser.readline()
    if len(linein)<10 : continue
    date   = str(datetime.now().date())
    date   = date[:10]            
    time   = str(datetime.now().time())
    time   = time[:8]
    outline = date + tab + time + tab + linein
    f = open("pv.dat","a")
    f.write(outline)
    f.close()
```

On the Arduino it just takes a reading every minute and sends it with a Serial.println

The Pi adds date and time stamps and saves it, where I run gnuplot to see the results.  Gnuplot knows how to interpret the tabbed data columns.  This way minimizes the size of data files it saves.

For your application, it would be easy to set up an input event routine (See [Serial event)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) on the Arduino to process any commands from the Pi to activate the linear actuator.  The Pi would send a serial command based on its clock, in Python code.

As for the relay wiring, connect power to the centers of two of them, then their NO contacts to the other relays so they can be used to switch polarity.  Your code can determine which way of wiring is most convenient.  (Note that all of these relays are active-low).  Your input from the Pi  should cause the Nano to first set the correct polarity then turn on the voltage, to make the actuator move either direction.  You can use delay() to determine how long the motors run, or depend on the internal limit switches to stop their travel.

One important thing to do is, once you have the Rpi set up the way you want (which includes the sketch for the Nano), make a backup .img file of the SD card with [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download) just in case.

Comment: I, too, do my testing on an Arduino, but fyi, just because 5v is present doesn't mean you need to chain one to a Pi to get the desired results for a 5v relay. A transistor, or even a Pi-capable 3.3v relay feeding a 5v relay will do the job all the same. It would be great if you could show some code and wiring diagram to show how you actually get things done.

Comment: Good idea.  I edited the post with more details, code, and photos.

Comment: Here is a smaller relay board that contains two DPDT relay switches that can be controlled by just two Arduino pins:  https://www.amazon.com/ELECTRONICS-SALON-Signal-Module-Version-Arduino/dp/B00SKG6OM4